# How to use custom yml file reference to map values using Mapstruct in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, yaml, mapstruct

I am working on a spring boot project where Mapstruct is being used to transform incoming JSON to an object. JSON contains address information like cityCode, stateCode. And that mapping of code-to-name is saved in a custom address.yml file. (To configure a custom yml in a springboot project, I referred this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource) and was able to fetch data from AddressProperties in @Service layer class.)

I need name of city from yml using cityCode in JSON, while mapping incoming JSON to the Address object.
For that created a Mapper - AddressMapper.

Here is the class -

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",  unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class AddressMapper {

    @Autowired
    AddressProperties addressProperties;

    @Mappings({@Mapping(target = "cityName", expression = "java(addressProperties.getCity().get(address.getCityCode()))")})
    abstract Address codeToName(AddressDTO address);
}
```

Another approach -

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",  unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public abstract class AddressMapper {

    @Autowired
    AddressProperties addressProperties;
    
    abstract Address codeToName(AddressDTO address);

    @AfterMapping
    public void populateNames(@MappingTarget Address address, AddressDTO addressDTO){
        address.setCityName(addressProperties.getCity().get(addressDTO.getCityCode()));
    }
}
```

However, for both approaches, I am getting `NullPointerException`.
`AddressProperties` is null in both cases.

Is there any way to map and set the value of fields from the custom yml file in Mapstruct or Spring boot?

This is AddressProperties.java file, which points to 'address.yml' and load values :

```
@Data
@Builder
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:address.yml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class AddressProperties {

    @Value("${city}")
    private Map<String, String> city;

}
```

Here YamlPropertySourceFactory is referred from [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml-propertysource) article from Baeldung.

Address.yml

```
city:
  101: AL
  102: AK
  103: AZ
  104: AR
```

Comment: "AddressProperties is null in both cases." -> show us where you "declare"/how you load! ;)

Comment: I am able to get addressproperties ref but the 'city' map is null.

Comment: Show also please the (outline/structure of) yaml.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to Autowire property file with

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring",  unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
```

But the object was still null.

Tried another approach by passing property object in `@Context` and calling the mapper like this -

```
AddressMapper.INSTANCE.populateNames(AddressProperty property)
```

*I still wonder why using `componentmodel="spring"` did not provide the solution.*